# Should answers be edited to remove bad practices?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, specific-edit

Take the following update:

[image]

The OP suggested [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and the editor amended the answer to remove the OP's update. Now, I agree with the editor that this *is* a bad practice but I'm unsure whether their action was the correct one.

In these scenarios isn't the norm to leave a comment/show your disapproval through voting rather than amending the OP's answer to suit what you want, irrespective of the validity of the edit in a technical sense, or, is what the editor did fine?

Comment: I don't see why this particular case is "security through obscurity" as it clearly states "Base64 ...and then *encrypting* …" (converting bytes to Base64 and then again back to bytes for encryption does not sound … ideal … but definitely not insecure).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov because the OP is suggesting to encode the data purely to prevent people from being able to see it in its original form thus making it trivially harder to edit, it was in a question to do with preventing XSS / other attacks therefore this method would definitely be seen as "security through obscurity".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov is right: obscurity isn't the point; defeating SQL injection is the point.  Base64 can't contain quote characters. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table).  Encrypting seems pointless, but Base64 will work (at the expense of making indexing / searching on that field not usable).  It's not a terrible idea for defending against [2nd-order and lateral SQL injection](https://download.oracle.com/oll/tutorials/SQLInjection/html/lesson1/les01_tm_attacks.htm), when a later query (perhaps manually done by a DB admin) uses data from the DB as part of a query.

Comment: It seems like an ugly / inefficient solution, but worth considering if you don't trust other code or people who do queries on the database to always remember that data coming from the DB could still be malicious.

Comment: @PeterCordes with respect, I believe you have misunderstood the context. The question *is* asking about security, however the base64 method *is* security through obscurity i.e. encoding all the data so it is unreadable to a novice, I'm confident that any script kiddie worth their weight would know to that it is base64 and would then decode it trivially. The point of the editor to remove this specific paragraph was because security through obscurity is not a good principle to rely on when you have so many more sure fire ways to prevent XSS or SQL injection.

Comment: Truth be told, some basic validation to ensure the input you are receiving is what you are expecting alongside prepared statements and on output using `htmlspecialchars` should solve majority of your issues.

Comment: The original tags on the question included `[sql-injection]`; only a day later did the OP add `[xss]`.  The answer never explains the *purpose* of base64 encoding.  It seems obvious to me that it's potentially useful as a way of storing arbitrary data in a DB without ever sending anything but plain text through SQL queries, not for defending against people stealing your database.  And like I said, getting "nasty" data safely into your database with a prepared statement isn't always sufficient: 2nd-order SQL injection can attack unsafe interactive use of that data.

Comment: This is kind of a belt-and-suspenders approach which is unnecessary if all your code is safe, and your DB admins don't build queries out of data from the DB.  Even if that's the case, an extra layer of obscurity doesn't actively *hurt*.  Just be sure not to rely on it as your primary defence.  The security-through-obscurity argument isn't that every form of obscurity is bad, just that obscurity is not *sufficient*. (And that inventing your own unpublished cryptosystems is a terrible idea.) But I don't think the post was claiming that this is anything more than an extra layer vs. SQL injection.

Comment: @PeterCordes Regarding this particular case,  that "extra layer" probably not provide extra security, but it unnecessarily bloats the data size. Definitely not a good practice.

Comment: @user202729: Yeah, I would *not* recommend it in general.  But I think it's worth considering if you're very paranoid about 2nd-order SQL injection, and that outweighs performance / size.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you disagree with an answer's contents, downvote that answer.
You can also add a comment explaining what's wrong.

You don't edit the answer to remove the part you disagree with. That's a sure-fire way to get into an edit war.

Same goes for adding new content to answers. It's better to write a new answer and let that get voted on.

Comment: Should this edit be left as is or should it be rolled back, or would that then cause a rollback war?

Comment: Rolled back, absolutely. If the editor re-applies the edit, flag the answer so a moderator can intervene.

Comment: Rolled back with a comment pointing here. Thanks.

Comment: Except that people are scared to downvote because they lose rep

Comment: @alec935 People shouldn't worry about that one rep lost on a downvote. It's insignificant.

Comment: If it’s insignificant SO should remove it. You can’t have it both ways.

Comment: I thought that adding new content to answers to improve them was encouraged. Did that change?

Comment: There's a difference between improving an answer and completely changing what it says, @Mike. If you leave the meaning of the answer intact, you're fine. This case, however, completely removes an opinion / option / explanation from an answer. That was never okay.